# Finding the next blank cell in a column and write in it

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to write code for a work log. There are 3 columns: Date, Company, and Product Ordered.

I want to create a form with an input box for each column, in which you type the corresponding info. I'm having trouble finding the next empty cell down and then using an input box to set its value. It would look something like the photo attached.

[image: Example of what i want to achieve]

Comment: As a new SO member, I would suggest please go through this section [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

you want basically something like this:

```
Public Function startRow() As Integer
   startRow = 2
End Function
```

startRow is a function i have in every data table to ignore headers, sometimes also UI elements and to work with empty Sheets.

```
Private Function LastRow() As Integer
    Dim rangeObj As Range
    Set rangeObj = Tabelle3.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
If rangeObj Is Nothing Then
    LastRow = startRow
ElseIf rangeObj.Row < startRow Then
    LastRow = startRow
Else
    LastRow = rangeObj.Row
End If
End Function
```

This function Returns the number of the last used row, after you know this row, you can insert data below it. The If-Elseif-Else is  for empty Sheets and Sheets which are only containing the columntitle

Answer (score 0):

That code works, however each time i re-run the code it overwrites the values i put in the previous time, i.e it writes the values into row 2 every time, rather than dropping down to the next row and writing in there.

Comment: You should add a comment to the answer you are referencing, not an answer of your own.  The poster of that answer will not be notified of your question if you add an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Enum columnNumbers
    colDate = 1
    colCompany
    colProduct
End Enum

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim nextRow As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    nextRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, colDate).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ws.Cells(nextRow, colDate) = InputBox("Enter date value", "Date", Date)
    ws.Cells(nextRow, colCompany) = InputBox("Enter company name", "Company")
    ws.Cells(nextRow, colProduct) = InputBox("Enter product details", "Product")
End Sub
```

Assuming that your three columns are consecutive, assign the column number to the first enumerated value (eg, if the date column is E, set colDate = 5) and the subsequent enumerated variables will be automatically incremented by one (so colCompany = colDate + 1, etc).

Then use the inputbox to capture values.